# mount: mounting /dev/block/vold/179:98 on /data/sdext2 failed: Device or resource busy

Tags: link2sd

When I open Link2SD, it asks to recreate mount scripts: I use ext4. After a reboot, when I open the linked application, it gets stuck and black screen till reboot.

I use ext4 as the 2nd partition, but it shows ext2 in Link2SD, and all my applications are now stuck.

```
mount: mounting /dev/block/vold/179:98 on /data/sdext2 failed: Device or resource busy
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check with `mount` the mount points for `/dev/block/vold/179:98`. `umount` the according to mount points to free the device. Beware there could be damage if you interrupt a writing process.

Answer (score 0):

If the 2nd partition is mounted by Android itself, then try to unmount it in the Android System settings. After that, create the mount script by Link2SD again.

That helped me, but after rebooting, I have to do it again.